# The use of "point out" seems awkward, can someone explain why it is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

> As a Chinese-speaking democracy, points out Bonnie Glaser of the
> German Marshall Fund of the us, a Washington think-tank, Taiwan has
> long been valued by the United States as an alternative political
> model to the Communist-run mainland.

The use of "point out" seems awkward, can someone explain why it is grammatically correct?

To me, the sentence is ok if it is like this

> As a Chinese-speaking democracy,Taiwan has
> long been valued by the United States as an alternative political
> model to the Communist-run mainland.

But the phrase "points out Bonnie Glaser of the German Marshall Fund of the us" is just placed awkwardly in between.

Comment: The cited text features *very* clumsy "stylistic inversion". The main thing you should learn from it is ***Don't write like this**!*

Comment: no, the sentence is definitely ***not*** ok if it is as you suggested, because two fundamental tenants of journalism are to a) cite your sources, and b) not express opinions.  Mentioning something as someone else's opinion is news. Mentioning something without saying that it is someone else's opinion is expressing an opinion.

Comment: Neither is scraping other news articles. [headtopics.com](https://headtopics.com/uk/parallels-with-taiwan-colour-asian-views-of-the-war-in-ukraine-24314288) or [the economist](https://www.economist.com/asia/2022/02/26/parallels-with-taiwan-colour-asian-views-of-the-war-in-ukraine), or both, stole that from somewhere or each other. - I can't find it in quotes but it's all over the place, written the same horrible way.

Comment: @Mazura: You cannot assume theft (or copyright infringement) here, since you simply do not know the original source and who they may or may not have given the right to use the article.

Comment: @Mazura [CBS News](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/russia-ukraine-taiwan-china-intelligence-matters/) had an interview where it looks like this quote was paraphrased from.

Comment: "two fundamental tenants of journalism"

@MikeNakis the word is "tenets".

Comment: They messed up by already starting the sentence with *as*, so they couldn't say it again.  *'as Bonnie Glaser points out'* - so they wrote it backwards to accommodate.

Comment: "the German Marshall Fund of the us" rather than "the German Marshall Fund of the US" confused me for many seconds. I was wondering if there was a "the German Marshall Fund of the them" too.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom thanks for pointing this out. I am sorry for the mistake. I will leave it there though, because I cannot edit it anymore, and I do not want to delete it.

Answer (score 21):

It's a different word order that is equivalent to this:

> Bonnie Glaser of the German Marshall Fund of the US, a Washington think-tank, points out that, as a Chinese-speaking democracy, Taiwan has long been valued by the United States as an alternative political model to the Communist-run mainland.

It's not ungrammatical as they expressed it, but it is awkward - it packs too much into one sentence.

As to *points out*, it means about the same as *says*.

Comment: I'm not gonna bother resequencing for clarity (there will be alternatives, I'm sure), but I suspect the primary problem isn't really that the sentence tries to pack too much in. It's the clumsy word order that lets it down.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'd probably argue there are numerous causes of confusion: (1) The reversed word order (for subject and verb) is uncommon/unexpected. (2) The original sentence interrupts the main idea of the sentence ("As a Chinese-speaking democracy, [...], Taiwan has long been valued...") with the statement that Bonnie Glaser is pointing this out. (3) That statement in the middle of the sentence also packs in several descriptive phrases in a row ("of the German Marshall Fund of the US, a Washington think-tank") describing where Glaser works and then describing that organization itself.

Comment: And adding on to points (2) and (3): Both these phrases, which are being placed in the middle of another thought, are only set apart from the rest of the sentence by commas. I think that makes it even harder to understand the sentence. For instance, the commas around "a Washington think-tank" could be replaced with dashes or parentheses for clarity (in addition to the other changes Jack suggested), like so: "Bonnie Glaser of the German Marshall Fund of the US – a Washington think-tank – points out that, as a [...]"

Comment: I suggest FumbleFingers was not only right, but rather reserved.

Would Jtkasd mind first explaining how the "point out" of the Question is equivalent to "points out;' 

If the use of "point out" seems awkward, can anyone  explain how or why?

Comment: "As to *points out*, it means about the same as *says*" -- I think there is a subtle but important difference. *Point out* connotes that the thing or idea described is real and valid; someone (implied to be reliable) is remarking on an evident fact, as if literally pointing a finger at it. *Say* does not endorse the source's viewpoint in this way. It is similar to the difference between *know* and *believe* (to know is to have reliable, true belief).

Comment: I suspect that the original text was written by someone with german background. This style of inversion and nesting sentences is quite often seen in german. My first reaction was "Well that is an odd translation", because this looks like what you get if you try to translate word-by-word, instead of adopting the style and customs of the language you translate to.

Comment: @nanoman: Excellent point, succinctly expressed. For my money, that implication of "expressing a real-world *fact*" (rather than just the speaker's *opinion*) is also there (albeit somewhat weaker) if I say *Nanoman **observes / makes the observation** that we normally **say** what we **think**, but **point out** [undisputed] **facts*** (as opposed to *Nanoman **says** that...*).

Comment: @nanoman May also have been an aversion to using "say" when it wasn't actually a direct quote.

Comment: @Polygnome See Mark Folsey's answer for the explanation of the inverted ordering.

Answer (score 7):

It is common in journalism to start a sentence with all or part of the thing someone said, and indicate who said it later in the sentence. If Bonnie Glaser had already been introduced, or was otherwise familiar, the author might have written

> As a Chinese-speaking democracy, points out Bonnie Glaser, Taiwan has long been valued by the United States as an alternative political model to the Communist-run mainland.

Journalists do this because the thing being said in these cases is more important than who said it. So they often bury the speaker's name in the middle of the sentence, which is the least salient location.

But this kind of sentence-rearrangement becomes harder to follow when the pieces get too big. That's what went wrong in the original sentence.

Added later: I should say something about when the rules of grammar actually allow this kind of rearranging. Unfortunately, this is one of those things where native speakers know what they can do without being sure how to put the rules into words. Of course, normally the subject (Bonnie Glaser) comes first in the sentence, followed by the verb. But verbs of saying or thinking have a lot more flexibility. All three of the following are acceptable. (And in these examples I used direct quotation, but it also holds for indirect quotation as in the OP's example.)

> Jim said, "Ouch."

> "Ouch," said Jim.

> "Ouch," Jim said.

Note that, if your original sentence were "Jim ate a sandwich" then you absolutely cannot reverse it to "A sandwich, ate Jim."

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it's awkward because it has two levels of parenthesis. Anyone reading it out loud would need their normal register, a lower one, and an even *lower* one! A listener might well say, "Get on with it!"

[Jack O'Flaherty's solution](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310559/the-use-of-point-out-seems-awkward-can-someone-explain-why-it-is-grammaticall/310560#310560) is good. There are others, including:

> According to Bonnie Glaser of the German Marshall Fund of the US, a Washington think-tank, Taiwan has long been valued by the United States as an alternative political model to the Communist-run mainland.

It's US (capitalized), by the way. Unless it's us!

Answer (score -1):

I bet that it is missing quotation marks.  You now know why they are important.

"As a Chinese-speaking democracy," points out Bonnie Glaser of the German Marshall Fund of the us, a Washington think-tank, "Taiwan has long been valued by the United States as an alternative political model to the Communist-run mainland."

Comment: How do you know that sentence was a direct quote? Maybe it was just paraphrasing what  Bonnie Glaser said, in which case it most definitely should not have quotes.

Comment: The quote marks fit so well I really think I'm right.

Comment: @LawrenceC: How can you know whether this is a direct quote or not? If she didn't say those exact words, then you are wrong, pure and simple. Downvoting because of your comment.

Comment: >> The quote marks fit so well I really think I'm right.  Absolutely not a rule in English.

Comment: The fact that the quote marks "fit so well" just indicates that it sounds like something *somebody* could say in those exact words, it does not indicate that *this specific named person* said it in those exact words. Actually the lack of quotation marks should indicate that it was *not* said in those exact words.

Comment: It's common when paraphrasing to say "So-and-so said that ...", which is probably what makes this seem like a quote.  When you leave out "that", it will almost always sound like a quote, even if it's not actually. So you can't really jump to the conclusion.